# Integration and differentiation complicated equation

Tags: integration

What does this mean?

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left.\right|_{x=\pi} \int_{t=0}^x \frac{\cos (3t)}{\sqrt{1+t}} dt   $$

Do I have to differentiate after I find the integral?
Can anybody help me solve it?

It's too long and complicated to understand. Please explain with steps. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That "equation" is not an equation.

Comment: Sorry. I will edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are being asked to consider the integral from $t=0$ to $t=x$ as a function of $x$ with this integrand. Then you are asked to take the derivative of this function at the point $x=\pi$.

The fundamental theorem of calculus lets you avoid actually computing the integral, since:
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x f(t) \,dt = f(x)$$ provided that $f$ is continuous. Thus the derivative you want is simply the integrand evaluated at $\pi$.

Comment: So the answer is $ \frac{cos 3\pi}{\sqrt(1+\pi)} = \frac{-1}{\sqrt(1+\pi)} $ ?

Comment: Yes indeed it is :-)

Answer (score 2):

Hint

$$\frac{d}{dx}\Bigg|_{x=b}\int_a^x f(t)\,dt=f(x)\Bigg|_{x=b}=f(b)$$